# Java invalid stream header Problem

Tags: java, exception, serialization, stream

im writen a client-server app, and now i´m facing a problem that I dont know how to solve:

This is the client:

```
try
        {

            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);


            ObjectOutputStream ooos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket
                    .getOutputStream());
            SendMessage message = new SendMessage();

            message.numDoc = value.numDoc;
            message.docFreq = value.docFreq;

            message.queryTerms = query;
            message.startIndex = startIndex;
            message.count = count;
            message.multiple = false;
            message.ips = null;
            message.ports = null;

            message.value = true;
            message.docFreq = value.docFreq;
            message.numDoc = value.numDoc;
            ooos.writeObject(message);


            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket
                    .getInputStream());
            ComConstants mensajeRecibido;
            Object mensajeAux;
            String mensa = null;

            byte[] by = null;

            do
            {

                mensajeAux = ois.readObject();

                if (mensajeAux instanceof ComConstants)
                {


                    System.out.println("Thread by Thread has Search Results");

                    String test;

                    ByteArrayOutputStream testo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    mensajeRecibido = (ComConstants) mensajeAux;

                    byte[] wag;

                    testo.write(
                            mensajeRecibido.fileContent, 0,
                            mensajeRecibido.okBytes);

                    wag = testo.toByteArray();


                    if (by == null) {

                        by = wag;

                    }
                    else {

                        int size = wag.length;

                          System.arraycopy(wag, 0, by, 0, size);
                    }


                } else
                {

                    System.err.println("Mensaje no esperado "
                            + mensajeAux.getClass().getName());
                    break;
                }
            } while (!mensajeRecibido.lastMessage);




            //ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(by.toByteArray()); // bytes es el byte[]
            ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(by);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(bs);
            QueryWithResult[] unObjetoSerializable = (QueryWithResult[])is.readObject();
            is.close();

            //AQUI TOCARIA METER EL QUICKSORT

            XmlConverter xce = new XmlConverter(unObjetoSerializable, startIndex, count);
            String serializedd = xce.runConverter();



        tempFinal = serializedd;

            ois.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        i++;

        }
```

And this is the sender:

```
try
    {

        QueryWithResult[] outputLine;

        Operations op = new Operations();

        boolean enviadoUltimo=false;

        ComConstants mensaje = new ComConstants();
        mensaje.queryTerms = query;

        outputLine = op.processInput(query, value);

        //String c = new String();
        //c = outputLine.toString();
        //StringBuffer swa = sw.getBuffer();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bs= new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream (bs);
        os.writeObject(outputLine);
        os.close();

        byte[] mybytearray =  bs.toByteArray();

        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(mybytearray); 

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);

        int readed = bis.read(mensaje.fileContent,0,4000);


        while (readed > -1)
        {


            mensaje.okBytes = readed;


            if (readed < ComConstants.MAX_LENGTH)
            {
                mensaje.lastMessage = true;
                enviadoUltimo=true;
            }
            else
                mensaje.lastMessage = false;

            oos.writeObject(mensaje);


            if (mensaje.lastMessage)
                break;

            mensaje = new ComConstants();
            mensaje.queryTerms = query;

            readed = bis.read(mensaje.fileContent);
        }

        if (enviadoUltimo==false)
        {
            mensaje.lastMessage=true;
            mensaje.okBytes=0;
            oos.writeObject(mensaje);
        }

        oos.close();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the error log:

```
Thread by Thread has Search Results
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 20646520
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.tockit.comunication.ServerThread.enviaFicheroMultiple(ServerThread.java:747)
at org.tockit.comunication.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:129)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Where at `org.tockit.comunication.ServerThread.enviaFicheroMultiple(ServerThread.java:747)` is this line `ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(bs);` on the 1st code just after `while (!mensajeRecibido.lastMessage);`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

The value `20646520` is in ASCII `@A`.

ObjectInput/OutputStreams use a "magic" value at the beginning of the stream, to indicate it complies to the special serialization of the objects. (I think this was `0xCAFEBABE`, but I'm not sure)

This means in your situation that something has already read the stream before the ObjectInputStream has the chance to read the magic, or that the stream it reads is not producted by an ObjectOutputStream;

You assign the variable `by` to `wig` (or append), which is a byte array which is not generated by an ObjectOutputStream, as far as I can tell, since it uses `mensajeRecipido.fileContent`. I presume `mensajeRecipido.fileContent` is the content of an actual file. In this running instance is not of the same format as an ObjectOutputStream, and that's why you get the stream header exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
mensajeRecibido.filecontet comes from the sender code, its content of the messages i send.

I think that its of the same format from my point of view, but its very posible that i dont understad your statement or know what should i do.

Thanks :D

Comment: No idea yet of how to solve the problem :S

Comment: I don't see how you can possibly have converted an 8 digit number to two ASCII characters. The magic value is printed in hex. So the first byte is an ASCII space, as is the last, and the middle two seem to be lowercase letters. So clearly he isn't using an `ObjectOutputStream` at all, just writing text directly.