# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 54657374

Tags: java

I am trying to read a string which is send from client using Socket program, The code as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketServerExample {

    //static ServerSocket variable
    private static ServerSocket server;
    //socket server port on which it will listen
    private static int port = 5000;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        //create the socket server object
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        //keep listens indefinitely until receives 'exit' call or program terminates
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Waiting for client request");
            //creating socket and waiting for client connection
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            //read from socket to ObjectInputStream object
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            //convert ObjectInputStream object to String
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
            //create ObjectOutputStream object
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            //write object to Socket
            oos.writeObject("Hi Client "+message);
            //close resources
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            socket.close();
            //terminate the server if client sends exit request
            if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
        }
        System.out.println("Shutting down Socket server!!");
        //close the ServerSocket object
        server.close();
    }

}
```

But I am getting error as follows while reading the string from client:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 54657374
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:803)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
    at SocketServerExample.main(SocketServerExample.java:29)
```

I searched and not managed find the bug. Please help me.

Comment: maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622716/java-invalid-stream-header-problem

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Clearly you aren't sending the data with `ObjectOutputStream:` you are just writing the bytes.

- If you read with `readObject()` you must write with `writeObject().`
- If you read with `readUTF()` you must write with `writeUTF().`
- If you read with `readXXX()` you must write with `writeXXX(),` for most values of XXX.

Comment: @androidsuckzzz To read on an ObjectInputStream, you have to write to an ObjectOutputStream (or you have to do the same thing it does which I don't suggest you try).  You can't just write to any stream and assume it will work.

Comment: @SrujanBarai No you aren't. You are sending `"Test"` directly, or else you aren't getting this error.

Answer (score 9):

You can't expect `ObjectInputStream` to automagically convert text into objects.  The hexadecimal `54657374` is `"Test"` as text.  You must be sending it directly as bytes.

Comment: Hello, I am sending bytes directly from my cpp client to java server. How to read it in this case? iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 ); -- cpp client code for sending.

Comment: @Haramoz You should also send the length otherwise you can only send one message per stream. I would use blocking NIO with ByteBuffer with native ordered data.