# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 74001057

Tags: java, serialization

I'm now creating a simple TicTacToe game on Android phone.
I used java server to handle multiplayer part, but when I pair the players and 'new' the ObjectInputStream, it throw me the exception.

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 74001057
```

These is my server code when create a new game thread:

```
public GameThread(Socket Player1, Socket Player2) {
  this.Player1 = Player1;
  this.Player2 = Player2;
  System.out.println("GameThread Started!");
  //Exception throw at the codes below
  new ReceiveMessagesThread(this.Player1, this.Player2).start();
  new ReceiveMessagesThread(this.Player2, this.Player1).start();
}
```

These is my server codes for receiving message in a game thread:

```
// This is an inner class.
private class ReceiveMessagesThread extends Thread {

  private Socket SourceClient, DestinationClient;

  ReceiveMessagesThread(Socket SourceClient, Socket DestinationClient) {
    this.SourceClient = SourceClient;
    this.DestinationClient = DestinationClient;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        // Exception throw at the line below
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(this.SourceClient.getInputStream()); 

        switch (in.readByte()) {
          case ServerGlobal.BOARD_STATUS:
            GameBoard = (char[][]) in.readObject();
            SendBoardStatus(this.DestinationClient);
            break;
        }
      }
      catch (java.io.StreamCorruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        break;
      }
      catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GameThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code (i.e. the code that sends and receives messages in this case) in your question, not link to your entire project. That will make more people understand your question and you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @KErlandsson edited.
Sorry, because i'm though I'm using thread, the problem might occurred somewhere else that I don't know.
So I post the whole project here~~

Comment: You might want to check out for example this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262160/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header-54657374

Comment: Post the sending code. You aren't detecting end of stream correctly either.

Answer (score 0):

Move the creation of the `ObjectInputStream` ahead of the loop. It tries to read a stream header placed there by the peer's `ObjectInputStream`, which you should likewise only create once. These streams should persist for the life of the socket, not be created anew for each send or receive.

Answer (score -1):

If you output the array of chars into `ObjectOutputStream` by separate chars, then you should read it also by chars, not as an array.

Also, check for consistent usage of `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`. In your code on github you use `DataInputStream` in some places.

Also ensure that every wrapping of `socket.getInputStream()` with `new ObjectInputStream()` matches corresponding unwrapping of `socket.getOutputStream()` with `new ObjectOutputStream()`. Or better yet, wrap the socket streams in `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` only once, not every time you want to read/write something.