# Spring framework deserialize failed

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, serialization, jboss-4.0.x

What i am doing is serializing a class and store it in database, then reading it and deserialize it using `SpringFramework`, and getting an exception on deserialization bytes into class.

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to deserialize object
    at org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:68)
..
...
....
 Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: BB656430
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
     at org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:64)
```

Deserialization process:

```
MyClass formObject2 = (MyClass) SerializationUtils.deserialize(dbData);
```

I Serialization isn't important in this process but let have for hint

```
byte[] data = SerializationUtils.serialize(myForm);
```

**More**

- Obviously `MyClass implements java.io.Serializable`
- When i try this as a JavaApplication using
  `spring-core-3.2.0-RELEASE.jar` it is working fine. But on server it
  throws this exception.
- My wild guess is jars are conflicting at runtime, but I couldn't find
  it so far.
- My database column is `BINARY`, bytea

Comment: If you think that jars are conflicting, then you can check it via dependency hierarchy in your maven pom.xml file.

Comment: Project isn't maven base.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262160/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header-54657374

Comment: @imran question updated