# Am I serializing a SealedObject wrong?

Tags: java, android, encryption, serialization, nfc

So for an Android project I need to write to and read from a NFC tag. My NFCReader code works just fine when I try to write and read plain text records. However, to make the system secure, I'm trying to seal my `TagProfile` object in a `SealedObject` with a `Cipher`, and then serialize that `SealedObject` to write it into the NFC tag. To read the tag, I'm trying to deserialize the `SealedObject` and then get the `TagProfile` object from it.

The write code seems to work just fine. However, when I try to read the tag, I get the following error: `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 02656EAC`

I'm wondering if I'm either writing or reading the data wrong. I think it has to do with the serialization more than with the encryption. I've looked for this error but I can't find an example with the same header that's being thrown. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262160/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header-54657374) but I'm using ByteArrayStreams and ObjectStreams for both input and output. In any case, here are my `èncryptProfile()` and `decryptProfile()` methods, which also perform the serialization. The former is called when creating the `NdefRecord` to be written, and the latter when building a `TagProfile` from the `NdefRecord` payload.

```
    private byte[] encryptProfile(TagProfile tagProfile) throws InvalidKeyException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        SealedObject sealedProfile = new SealedObject(tagProfile, cipher);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(sealedProfile);
        oos.flush();
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

...

    private TagProfile decryptProfile(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        SealedObject sealedObject = (SealedObject) ois.readObject();
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        return (TagProfile) sealedObject.getObject(cipher);
    }
```

The error is thrown when I instance and initialize the `ObjectInputStream ois` at `decryptProfile()`. The `Cipher` and `Key` objects are instanced globally.

EDIT: I'm adding the code I use to write the `NdefMessage` to the tag and to build the `TagProfile` from it. Worked fine using plain texts (albeit with a slightly different implementation).

```
// ---------- WRITE

    public void writeToTag(TagProfile profile, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

/*      Plain text implementation:

        NdefRecord[] records = {
                createRecord(profile.id),
                createRecord(profile.name),
                ...
        };
        NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
*/      
        NdefRecord[] encryptedRecord = {
                createRecord(profile)
        };
        NdefMessage encryptedMessage = new NdefMessage(encryptedRecord);

        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        ndef.connect();
        ndef.writeNdefMessage(encryptedMessage);
        ndef.close();
    }

    private NdefRecord createRecord(TagProfile tagProfile) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

        byte[] profileBytes = encryptProfile(tagProfile);
        String lang       = "en";
        byte[] langBytes  = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
        int    langLength = langBytes.length;
        int    bytesLength = profileBytes.length;
        byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + langLength + bytesLength];

        payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

        System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1, langLength);
        System.arraycopy(profileBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, bytesLength);

        NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,  NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,  new byte[0], payload);

        return recordNFC;
    }

// ---------- READ

    private TagProfile buildProfile(NdefMessage[] msgs) throws EmptyTagException, ImproperTagException{

        try {
            if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) throw new EmptyTagException();
            String[] records = new String[msgs[0].getRecords().length];

            if(records.length == tagLength) { // tagLength is the number of records I expect.
                return decryptProfile(msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload());
            } else throw new ImproperTagException();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new TagProfile();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code should work provided you're passing the same key and it is a symmetric key.

Comment: And assuming you passed around the byte array losslessly.

Comment: @user207421 the thing is it doesn't even get to the decryption part; it breaks when instancing the `ois`. I'm adding the code that I use to write the `NdefMessage` and to build the profile.

Comment: So that means you must have broken the byte array. It should start with 0XACED. Have you converted it to `String` and back for example?  NB Your post says that it happened 'when I try to read the tag', which I assumed meant calling `SealedObject.getObject()`.

Comment: Simple. 02 is the length of `en`, and `en` in hex is 0X656E. You have failed to remove the length and language bytes from the payload before decrypting.